# $NotTooManyP^{cc}$ class in communication complexity

Tags: complexity-classes, communication-complexity, nondeterminism

Class $P^{cc}$ is class of languages admitting deterministic communication protocol with ***polylog*** bits of communication.

Class $NP^{cc}$ is class of languages admitting nondeterministic communication protocol with ***polylog*** size witness.

Class  $FewP^{cc}$  is class of languages admitting nondeterministic communication protocol with ***polylog*** size witness, where each input has at most ***polylog*** correct witnesses.

It was proven that $FewP^{cc} = P^{cc}$ [1]. My question is about what happens if we allow not too many correct witnesses instead of few.

Let class $NotTooManyP^{cc}$ be class of languages admitting nondeterministic communication protocol with ***polylog*** size witness, where each input has at most ***polynomial*** correct witnesses. Is this class different from $P^{cc}$? If yes, how much weaker is this class then $NP^{cc}$?

Answer (score 1):

When the inputs are the [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), set *non*-disjointness is in NP<sup>cc</sup> with witnesses

from {0,1,2,3,...,n-2,n-1} $\big(\hspace{-0.04 in}$so in particular is in NotTooManyP<sup>cc</sup>$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)$, ​ but by [this paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~thomasw/papers/dsj.pdf),

the coU[SBP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#sbp) (and thus also P) communication complexity of that problem is $\Theta$(n).

By padding, that means we leave coUSBP<sup>cc</sup> $\big(\hspace{-0.04 in}$and thus also P<sup>cc</sup>$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)$ ​ as soon

as the number of witnesses is no longer polylogarithmically-bounded.

Also, for all functions ​ f : {0,1,2,3,...} $\to$ (0,1] , ​ if the version with at most

n<sup>f(n)</sup> correct witnesses equals NP<sup>cc</sup> then f has a positive lower bound.

Proof:

Let f be any function from {0,1,2,3,...} to (0,1] such that the problem at

the start of this answer can be solved with at most n<sup>f(n)</sup> correct witnesses.

Let ​ g : {0,1,2,3,...} $\to$ {0,1,2,3,...} ​ be given by

g(0) = 0 = g(1) ​ and otherwise ​ g(n) = (log(n))<sup>1/(f(n))</sup> ​ .

g(0) = 0 ​ and ​ g(1) = 0 < 1 ​ and ​ for all other inputs n,

g(n) = (log(n))<sup>1/(f(n))</sup> < n<sup>1/(f(n))</sup> ≤ n<sup>1/1</sup> = n<sup>1</sup> = n ​ .

Accordingly, consider the problem ​ ​ non-disjointness of subsets of ​ {0,1,2,3,...,(g(n))-2,(g(n))-1} ​ whose inputs are padded indicator functions.

By removing the padding, that problem can be solved with at most (g(n))<sup>f(n)</sup> correct witnesses.

For all integers n such that ​ 1 < n , ​ (g(n))<sup>f(n)</sup> = $\big(\hspace{-0.05 in}$(log(n))<sup>1/(f(n))</sup>$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)^{\hspace{.02 in}f\hspace{.02 in}(n)}$ = (log(n))<sup>(1/(f(n)))$\cdot$f(n)</sup> = (log(n))<sup>1</sup> .

Thus the problem is in FewP<sup>cc</sup>, so by the result you mentioned, it's also in P<sup>cc</sup>.

By the communication lower bound in this answer's starting sentence, that means g is

at most polylogarithmic, so 1/(f(n)) is bounded above, so f has a positive lower bound.

I'm not aware of any other results about limited-ambiguity versions of NP<sup>cc</sup>,

although with inputs as in the rest of this answer, (paddings of, if necessary) the problems

" ​ Does the intersection have at least _ elements? ​ "

seem like natural candidates for separating those classes.

$\big(\hspace{-0.04 in}$On the other hand, I wasn't even aware of ​ [unambiguous](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:U#up)P<sup>cc</sup> = P<sup>cc</sup> ,

and still know neither a proof of that nor a reference for that.$\hspace{-0.03 in}\big)$

Comment: That's a very nice observation! Do you have any ideas on the other direction: is this class different from $NP^{cc}$?

Comment: I just came up with and showed a result in the other direction, although it $\hspace{1.89 in}$ doesn't reach the class you're asking about. ​ ​